# highlighting the word using span tags

Tags: javascript

I don't know **what** is the next code, i'm very confusing for this code.
i create this **highlight** that every word will have it's own span.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et perferendis quia est dolores eligendi  numquam labore et voluptatem

will **turn** into

> Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet.,Et perferendis,quia,est,dolores,eligendi,numquam,labore, et,voluptatem

then replace the **comma** (,) to:

```
</span><span>
```

and this is the **result:**

```
Lorem</span><span>ipsum</span><span>dolor</span><span>sit</span><span>amet.</span><span>Et</span> ...
```

> if a span contains paragraph tag, it will colored to green:

```
<span style="color: green"><p>paragraph</p></span>
```

and what's **next?**

```
//highlight the whole editor
var editor = document.querySelector("#rescript-editor");
function highlight_package() {
    const highlight_split = editor.value.split(" ");
    const highlight_span = highlight_split.toString().replace(/,/gi, "</span><span>");
    var highlight_count = 0;
    try {
        highlight_count++
        setInterval(function(){
            var highlight_detect = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[highlight_count];
            highlight_coloring();
            // WHAT'S NEXT??
        }, 100);
    } catch(e) {
        
    }
}
function highlight_coloring() {
    if( highlight_detect.value == "<p>" || highlight_detect.value == "</p>" ) {
        highlight_detect.style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

Comment: How paragraph will be added after added the <span> tag?

Comment: Define input-output properly.